# Typescript no me detecta una propiedad heredada

Tags: typescript, herencia

Ando aprendiendo Typescript y tengo un error el cuál no he podido solucionar, una propiedad heredada me da error al querer mostrarla en consola. Según la teoria al ser protected debería ser accesible desde las subsclases como es el caso de doors, pero no es así me aparece el siguiente error:"Property 'doors' does not exist on type 'ElectricCar'.ts(2339)"

```
//Ampliacion de una clase

class Cars1{
    //Properties
    private static numberOfCars: number = 0;
    protected _make: string;
    protected _color: string;
    protected _doors: number;

    //Constructor
    constructor(make: string, color: string, doors: number){
        this._make = make;
        this._color = color;
        this._doors = doors;
        Cars1.numberOfCars++;//Increments the value of the static property
    }

    //Methods
    public static getNumbersofCars(): number{
        return Cars1.numberOfCars;
    }

    protected Worker(){
        return this._make;
    }
}

class ElectricCar  extends Cars1{
    // Properties
    private _range: number;
    
    //Constructor
    constructor(make: string, color: string, range: number, doors = 2){
        super(make, color, doors);
        this._range = range;
    }

    //Accesors
    get range(){
        return this._range;
    }

    set range(range){
        this._range = range;
    }

    //Methods
    charge(){
        console.log(this.Worker() + " is charging.");
    }
}

let spark = new ElectricCar("Spark Motors",'silver', 124, 2);
let eCar = new ElectricCar("Electric Car Co.", 'black', 263);
console.log(spark.doors);
console.log(eCar.doors);         // returns the default, 2
spark.charge();                  // returns "Spark Motors is charging"
```

Comment: Dos errores: 1- Las propiedades privadas no se heredan. 2- La propiedad se llama `_doors` no `doors`.

Comment: Tienes razón, la cuestión es que no quiero que sea public, probé con protected, lo cuál debería funcionar al ser una subclasede Cars1 pero me sigue saliendo el error.
Property '_doors' is protected and only accessible within class 'Cars1' and its subclasses.ts(2445)

Comment: El código es texto... no lo pongas como imagen. No todo el mundo puede ver imágenes, ni tiene el mismo esquema de colores o puede tener problemas de visión... las imágenes no se adaptan a los dispositivos, el texto si. Por favor, ya que el código es texto, trátalo como tal! Usa el botón [edit] y pon tu código en formato texto. Además, como ya te dijeron, las propiedades privadas no se heredan... tal cual está tu pregunta no tiene sentido puesto que ya te han respondido, te recomiendo actualizarla e indicar los cambios que has hecho.

Comment: Muchas gracias Benito-B la verdad soy nuevo en StackOverflow y pense que colocar mucho código podría generarme multas o algo así.

Comment: Multas no, pero el rechazo de la comunidad expresado en down votes si. Haz clic en [edit] y cambia lo que haga falta. Saludos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La solución a tu problema sería la siguiente:

```
    //Ampliacion de una clase

    class Cars1{
        //Properties
        private static numberOfCars: number = 0;
        protected _make: string;
        protected _color: string;
        protected _doors: number;

        //Constructor
        constructor(make: string, color: string, doors: number){
            this._make = make;
            this._color = color;
            this._doors = doors;
            Cars1.numberOfCars++;//Increments the value of the static property
        }

        //Methods
        public static getNumbersofCars(): number{
            return Cars1.numberOfCars;
        }

        protected Worker(){
            return this._make;
        }
    }

    class ElectricCar  extends Cars1{
        // Properties
        private _range: number;
        
        //Constructor
        constructor(make: string, color: string, range: number, doors = 2){
            super(make, color, doors);
            this._range = range;
        }

        //Accesors
        get range(){
            return this._range;
        }

        set range(range){
            this._range = range;
        }

        //Methods
        charge(){
            console.log(this.Worker() + " is charging.");
        }
        
        //Aquí la solución
        get doors() {
            return this._doors;
        }
    }

    let spark = new ElectricCar("Spark Motors",'silver', 124, 2);
    let eCar = new ElectricCar("Electric Car Co.", 'black', 263);
    console.log(spark.doors);
    console.log(eCar.doors);         // returns the default, 2
    spark.charge();                  // returns "Spark Motors is charging"
```

Y aqui una breve explicación y ejemplo diferente:

En TypeScript, la palabra clave protected se utiliza para modificar el acceso a un miembro de una clase. Un miembro de clase protegido es accesible solo desde dentro de la clase y de cualquier clase que herede de ella.

Por ejemplo, si tienes una clase Animal con un miembro de clase protegido llamado _age, ese miembro solo será accesible dentro de la clase Animal y de cualquier clase que herede de ella. Si tienes otra clase que no hereda de Animal, no podrá acceder a ese miembro protegido.

Aquí tienes un ejemplo de cómo podría usarse la palabra clave protected en TypeScript:

```
    class Animal {
        protected _age: number;
    
        constructor(age: number) {
        this._age = age;
        }
    
        getAge(): number {
        return this._age;
        }
    }
    
    class Cat extends Animal {
        constructor(age: number) {
        super(age);
        }
    
        meow(): void {
        console.log(`I am ${this._age} years old.`);
        }
    }
    
    const cat = new Cat(3);
    cat.meow(); // imprime "I am 3 years old."
```

En este ejemplo, la clase Cat hereda de Animal y tiene acceso al miembro protegido _age de la clase padre. Sin embargo, si intentaras acceder a _age directamente desde afuera de la clase Animal o de cualquier clase que herede de ella, obtendrías un error de compilación.

Answer (score 2):

`protected` significa que la propiedad puede heredarse y ser accedida desde **adentro** de la clase hija. En tu caso, la instrucción: `console.log(spark.doors)`, está exponiendo al público esa propiedad y de ahí el error ya que se rompe la encapsulación.

Eso se puede arreglar agregando un método que sea el que retorne el valor de la propiedad:

```
class ElectricCar  extends Cars1{
  getDoors(){
    return this.doors
  }
}
const spark = new ElectricCar();
console.log(spark.getDoors());
```

Comment: Lobos muchas gracias, la verdad soy nuevo en esto  y el aclarar esta duda me servirá a futuro en esto.